# MVVM : how to make view model set fields of clean model to persist view changes to database

Tags: mvvm, prism

In MVVM application with clean model (not implementing interfaces like INotifyPropertyChabged), the View Model Contains properties bound to the View and these properties get its values from the model object contained in the view model and should set the value of its properties when view changes one of the controls that are bound to these properties.
the propblem is when the view change; the changes are captured by the bound view model properties but the properties can't set the model object fields, the model doesn't change. I need the model fields to accept setting by the view model properties, then i can persist the updated model into the database taking into account that it is a clean model.

Here part of the view model code

```
public class SubsystemDetailsViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged, ISubsystemDetailsViewModel
    {
        #region Fields
        //Properties to which View is bound
        private int? _serial;
        public int? Serial
        {
            get { return Subsystem.Serial; }
            set
            {
                //Subsystem.Serial=value;
                _serial = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Serial");
            }
        }

        private string _type;
        public string Type
        {
            get { return Subsystem.Type; }
            set
            {
                //Subsystem.Type = value;
                _type = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Type");
            }
        }


       //remaining properties ....


        #endregion

        //Service
        private readonly ISubsystemService _subsystemService;



        //Reference to the View
        public ISubsystemDetailsView View { get; set; }

        //Event Aggregator Event
        private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

        //Commands
        public ICommand ShowTPGCommand { get; set; }
        public DelegateCommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }

       //
        private bool _isDirty;

        //Constructor ************************************************************************************************
        public SubsystemDetailsViewModel(ISubsystemDetailsView View, ISubsystemService subsystemService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _subsystemService = subsystemService;

            this.View = View;
            View.VM = this;

            //EA-3
            if (eventAggregator == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("eventAggregator");
            this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            //Commands
            this.ShowTPGCommand = new DelegateCommand<PreCommissioning.Model.Subsystem>(this.ShowTestPacks);
            this.UpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.UpdateSubsystem, CanUpdateSubsystem);


        }


        //****************************************************************************************************************
        //ICommand-3 Event Handler 
        //this handler publish the Payload "SelectedSubsystem" for whoever subscribe to this event
        private void ShowTestPacks(PreCommissioning.Model.Subsystem subsystem)
        {
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<ShowTestPacksEvent>().Publish(SelSubsystem);
        }
        //===============================================================================================
        private void UpdateSubsystem()
        {

            _subsystemService.SaveChanges(Subsystem);
        }

        private bool CanUpdateSubsystem()
        {
            return _isDirty;
        }
        //*******************************************************************************************
        public void SetSelectedSubsystem(PreCommissioning.Model.Subsystem subsystem)
        {
            this.SelSubsystem = subsystem;

        }

        //************************************************************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Active subsystem >> the ItemSource for the View
        /// </summary>
        private PreCommissioning.Model.Subsystem _subsystem;
        public PreCommissioning.Model.Subsystem Subsystem
        {
            get
            { 
                //return this._subsystem;
                GetSubsystem(SelSubsystem.SubsystemNo);
                return this._subsystem;

            }

            set
            {
                if (_subsystem != value)
                {
                    _subsystem = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Subsystem");
                }

            }

        }



        //Call the Service to get the Data form the Database
        private void GetSubsystem(string SSNo)
        {
            this._subsystem = _subsystemService.GetSubsystem(SSNo);


        }





        #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            _isDirty = true;
            UpdateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Subsystem is the model object which is populated using GetSubsystem() method. the view model properties like Serial get its value from the model as shown. i tried to set the model properties as shown in the commented out line in set part of the property but no change happen to the Subsystem object, always keep its original values

Comment: Is there a reason the lines in your properties that set the Model's properties are commented out...because, well, that would be the reason it's not working. Aside from that, are you getting any errors in your output window?

Comment: @Ryan: it was commented out because i tried another way to go around this problem and it worked but i think it is not the right way to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `GetSubsystem` returns a new subsystem every time, that's your problem. In the 'set' for the properties you're binding to the view, you're calling the public property "Subsystem", not the private field you've created. So, every single time you set a property from the view, you are calling Subsystem.get which calls `GetSubsystem(SelSubsystem.SubsystemNo);`.

I think, in your ViewModel properties', you want to change it to:

```
//Properties to which View is bound
public int? Serial
{
    get { return _subsystem.Serial; }
    set
    {
        _subsystem.Serial=value; // NOTE THE USE OF THE PRIVATE FIELD RATHER THAN THE PROPERTY
        OnPropertyChanged("Serial");
    }
}

public string Type
{
    get { return _subsystem.Type; }
    set
    {
        _subsystem.Type = value; // NOTE THE USE OF THE PRIVATE FIELD RATHER THAN THE PROPERTY
        OnPropertyChanged("Type");
}
```

Comment: thanks alot, your idea is right, only one problem remaining: an exception is thrown @ "get { return _subsystem.Serial; }" saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." _subsystem is null but it work fine when i replace it by "get { return Subsystem.Serial; }" only for the first property.

Comment: Because _subsystem isn't being set. You aren't calling GetSubsystem any longer, but you are when you call Subsystem.Serial. Call GetSubsystm from somewhere (constructor?) and you should be good

Comment: If I'm right, can you please mark as answer so others can be helped

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference in your view-model to the model and the view-model will pass the values to the model.  Your view-model will implement INotifyPropertyChanged and will be the datacontext of your view.  In your view-model, write your bound properties like this:

```
private string yourProperty;
public string YourProperty
{
get { return yourProperty; }
set
{
if (value == yourProperty)
    return;
yourProperty= value;
YOUR_MODEL_REFERENCE.YourProperty= yourProperty;
this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.YourProperty);
}
}
```

Comment: same result, model doesn't change: by the way the model fields are populated by a service that grap those fields from database and assign them to the model.

Comment: Post a code sample.  This is standard stuff and should be easy to fix.  Also, you've confused me with the service/model comment.

Comment: @@Big dady : thanks for trying to help. i edited  my question above to attach part of the view model code

Comment: @Hussein...Your setters look okay, but why are the model lines commented out?  Put a breakpoint there and see what happens.  Also, you're injecting your view into the view-model.  Why?  That's not a usual practice in the MVVM world.  The view-model should have no knowledge of the view.

Comment: :the model lines were commented out because i was trying something else after this solution failed. You are right View and view model should be ignorant about each other and i'll try to modify this by removing view injection. Also my problem was as Ryan sent above the GetSubsystem() returns a new subsystem every time.